Difference Piano dolce and piano con suono più espr
since I have this new piece on the violin, which I am trying to learn, I just can’t get that difference between piano dolce and piano con suono più espr. … It’s really hard to imagine which both sound like, because my instinct would  play the second one louder, but it’s still piano, so I am lost..
Does somebody have a specific technique, which I could try or just an idea of how it should sound like?
Thanks

Please edit you post to add the title, composer, measure numbers, and an image of the parts in question. These can all affect the answer, because music instructions have different meanings in different contexts.

Are you clear on the translation? These aren't just about volume, but expression. They're both piano, but one is "sweet" and the other "with a more expressive tone." Both of those, of course, are very subjective directions and leave a lot of room for you to decide how exactly they sound, let alone how to produce them. I have some general recommendations—for instance, I usually recommend that dolce gets a lighter but faster bow, and espressivo might have implications about vibrato and rubato—but I think I'll give you a chance to show the context before I make an answer.

@AndyBonner - if anyone can provide an answer, it'll be you!

I would actually expect "dolce" and "con suono più espr." to be opposites to a certain extent. My understanding is that "espr." can afford to go overboard with expression, while "dolce" cannot - anything too "dolce" comes off as schmaltz.

'Piano' is reasonably objective (though still dependent on context).   The other terms, 'sweetly' and 'with a more expressive tone' are much more subjective, and can involve more than just volume.    Just play them both quietly for now and see where the music takes you!

Just who is it that is slap happy with the dvs with no explanation? Hiding behind anonymity?

No dv from me, though I do think we'll be able to offer better answers if the OP edits to identify the piece.

(Also, part of my answer would be just how intentionally subjective and vague piano is. "Soft?" Just how soft is "soft?" Softer than "loud," certainly, but how loud is "loud?" The vagary is intentional, and works much better than eg specifying a decibel reading.)
